# Часы в iOS-приложении

Tags: xcode, ios

Как сделать приложение,  на экране которого отображается время? Спасибо.

Comment: В iOS такое сделать не возможно, это противоречит всему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

советую купить какой-то учебник.
делается это просто - создаете проект - application - single view application
на storyboard размещаете Label.
теперь делаете outlet ссылку с кода на Label:

file.h:@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Label;

file.m:

@synthesize Label;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{

```
[super viewDidLoad];

NSDate *dateToday =[NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[format setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *string = [format stringFromDate:dateToday];

Label.text=string;
```

}